# Unable to fetch data through IMPORTXML from NSE website in Google sheets

Tags: google-sheets, web-scraping, google-sheets-formula, stock, stockquotes

I am trying to fetch current/ latest price from a dynamic  content from National Stock Exchange (India) website in a cell in google sheets. The formula is:

`=importxml("https://www.nseindia.com/live_market/dynaContent/live_watch/get_quote/GetQuoteFO.jsp?underlying=NIFTY&instrument=OPTIDX&strike=11400.00&type=CE&expiry=27SEP2018"),"//ul[@class='stock']/li[@class='active']/span[@id='lastPrice']")`

Not getting the correct value.

Comment: what is the expected value and what are you getting right now?

Comment: The expected value is 299.70 whereas it returns --

Answer (score -1):

Instead use `=GOOGLEFINANCE("NSE:INFY", "all", DATE(2021,5,21), DATE(2021,6,24), "DAILY")`